# WebDriver cannot be resolved to a type,ChromeDriver cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: selenium

package Purpose;

//import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;

//import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicInternalFrameTitlePane.SystemMenuBar;

public class program {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
```

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "F://ChromeDriver//chromedriver_win32 (3)//chromedriver.exe");

System.out.println("Hello");

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

driver.get("https://www.quora.com/");

```
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

it seems that only the path to the driver can be an issue.
choose on of the following methods:

1. place the driver in the same directory as the java file you are trying to run.
2. add chromedriver.exe to PATH environment variable (see how [here](https://www.architectryan.com/2018/03/17/add-to-the-path-on-windows-10/))

and then use setProperty like the below:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe")
```

Comment: Still Facing the same issue

Comment: seems strange,
can you try and run the following:

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
 
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
 
public class TestChrome {
 
public static void main(String[] args) {
 
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe");
 
// Initialize browser
WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
 
// Open facebook
driver.get("http://www.facebook.com");
 
// Maximize browser
 
driver.manage().window().maximize();
 
}
 
}

and if there is an error , please copy-paste it in the comment.